# Need help identifying multi-colored grasshopper

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I was out hiking with my friend when we ran across what I presume to be a grasshopper. It didn't seem very startled by our presence, and we were able to get some pretty cool pictures. I've been having trouble finding out what species it is. I was hiking near Albuquerque, New Mexico, and the grasshopper was about 1 - 1.5 inches in size. It was about midday when I saw it.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the (tour)[https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour]. Can you add some more detail to the post - where you saw this insect, when, and what size it was?

Answer (score 4):

It's what's called a Rainbow or Painted Grasshopper (*Dactylotum bicolor*).

[image]

You can learn more at [Bug Guide Species Dactylotum bicolor](http://bugguide.net/node/view/31526) (where the picture is found) or Wikipedia' article on [Dactylotum bicolor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactylotum_bicolor). The colour and pattern is very unmistakable.

Comment: I edited to add a picture (as is the custom when identifying something. Hope that's ok. :)

Comment: Perfectly fine if you edit it. I don't have enough time to help out in that department on SE so if others do, I'm only too happy for the help!